# How to Integrate Dropbox with Xamarin forms App using Nuget packages

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package, dropbox-api

I am working on a xamarin multiplatform application. I want to integrate dropbox with my application when I click on the dropbox button I need to redirect to the dropbox app to select the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the  third party libraries: [Xamarin.Dropbox.Api](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Dropbox.Api/):

> Portable class library for accessing the Dropbox v2 API specifically for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS to fix a depedency issue with the standard package.